Find all positive integers $a$ such that $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^{a}-1}{n^{a}+1}$ is rational.
I was discussing this question with a friend and it is not hard to check that a=1 and a=3 works. Are they the only ones? I tried rewriting $n^{a}-1$ and $n^{a}+1$ into a product of roots of unity but even then I did not get any meaningful results, just a product of gamma functions with complex inputs. How would I solve this?
